# Is there a conversion from xamGeographicMap tile x,y to geographic coordinates (lat, long)?

Tags: wpf, bing-maps, infragistics, wms

I'm trying to get my `xamGeographicMap` (in the Infragistics WPF controls) to retrieve its background tiles from a WMS service running on an internal GeoServer. This service requires that you provide it with a lat/long bounding box as opposed to tile x/y positions. However, when I override `GetTileLayers` in my derived `MapTileSource`, I am only provided with `tilePositionX`, `tilePositionY`, and `tileLevel`. How do I convert this to lat/long?

I ran into a similar issue when I was trying to hook up the Bing Maps WPF Control to the same service, but it was resolved by the `TileSystem` class provided here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx. I tried using the same conversion class with the `xamGeoGraphicMap` to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that you actually can use the `TileSystem` class provided on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx) for this. My error was in assuming that `tileLevel` was equal to `zoom`. After looking at some of the example Infragistics example code, I ran across the following line:

`var zoom = tileLevel - 8;`

Using this conversion in a call to `TileSystem.PixelXYToLatLong`, I was able to get the values I needed. Make sure that you convert you bounds from degrees to meters if your WMS service is expecting meters.

Answer (score 1):

You should write custom methods for this, since there aren't any built-in ones.

In the Infragsaitics forums a similar question is discussed. You can see the sample attached there:

http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/84442/423636.aspx#423636